# Twisted equivalent of ThreadPoolExecutor (in Scrapy pipeline)

Tags: python, multithreading, scrapy, twisted

I have to make API calls in a pipeline. Since the pipeline is running synchronously, these API requests are slowing it down to an unbearable point (like 2 items/min -- usually I have to do 20+ requests per item).

Usually, for IO-bound tasks like this one, I would resort to `concurrent.futures`:

```
import concurrent.futures


with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=8) as executor:
    executor.submit(func, args)  # ...
```

Unfortunately, since Scrapy is built on top of Twisted that would not work. What is the equivalent for Twisted? I found `reactor.callInThread` but didn't understand how to map it to the above solution.

Comment: Is this API blocking, or is there a twisted-compatible API that returns Deferreds?

Comment: @keturn Unfortunately it's blocking. I make requests via the `requests` library but it's becoming a bottleneck. I'd like to make these async.

Comment: To make non-blocking HTTP requests with Twisted, use [treq](https://github.com/twisted/treq) or the underlying [twisted.web.client](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html).

Comment: @keturn Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! I'll explore both alternatives.